# EMR cluster created with CloudFormation not shown

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, emr, amazon-emr

I have added an EMR cluster to a stack. After updating the stack successfully (CloudFormation), I can see the master and slave nodes in EC2 console and I can SSH into the master node. But AWS console does not show the new cluster. Even `aws emr list-clusters` doesn't show the cluster. I have triple checked the region and I am certain I'm looking at the right region.

Relevant CloudFormation JSON:

```
"Spark01EmrCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::EMR::Cluster",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "Spark01EmrCluster",
    "Applications": [
      {
        "Name": "Spark"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ganglia"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Zeppelin"
      }
    ],
    "Instances": {
      "Ec2KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"},
      "Ec2SubnetId": {"Ref": "PublicSubnetId"},
      "MasterInstanceGroup": {
        "InstanceCount": 1,
        "InstanceType": "m4.large",
        "Name": "Master"
      },
      "CoreInstanceGroup": {
        "InstanceCount": 1,
        "InstanceType": "m4.large",
        "Name": "Core"
      }
    },
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "spark-env",
        "Configurations": [
          {
            "Classification": "export",
            "ConfigurationProperties": {
              "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "BootstrapActions": [
      {
        "Name": "InstallPipPackages",
        "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
          "Path": "[S3 PATH]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "JobFlowRole": {"Ref": "Spark01InstanceProfile"},
    "ServiceRole": "MyStackEmrDefaultRole",
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.13.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is missing `VisibleToAllUsers` property, which defaults to `false`. Since I'm using AWS Vault (i.e. using STS AssumeRole API to authenticate), I'm basically a different user every time, so I couldn't see the cluster. I couldn't update the stack to add `VisibleToAllUsers` either as I was getting `Job flow ID does not exist`.

The solution was to login as root user and fix things from there (I had to delete the cluster manually, but removing it from the stack template JSON and updating the stack would probably have worked if I hadn't messed things up already).

I then added the cluster back to the template (with `VisibleToAllUsers` set to `true`) and updated the stack as usual (AWS Vault).

Comment: I think they've now changed the default to `true`. Not sure why that attribute is needed anyway

Comment: Nope, defaulted to `false` from Cloudformation for me. The default value is `true` when calling the API `SetVisibleToAllUsers`, though (which kinda makes sense)

Comment: I think they should deprecate the whole thing. Seems pointless to me. Also why do terminated clusters hang around forever and clutter the cluster list?